# ERROR: Dependency @types/html2canvas must be explicitly allowed using the "allowedNonPeerDependencies" option

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

I have installed the [html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas) in my angular library project and, when I compile in production mode (running the `ng build --prod` command), I'm receiving the following error:

> ERROR: Dependency @types/html2canvas must be explicitly allowed using
> the "allowedNonPeerDependencies" option.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can add the library to your [peerDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies) in [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json). *I strongly recommend using the  [peerDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies) strategy since exposes explicitly to others that your library depended on other libraries*:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {...},
    "peerDependencies": {
        ...
        "@types/html2canvas": "0.0.36",
        ...
    },
}
```

Or you can use the option on your ng-package.json:

```
{
    ...
    "lib": {
        "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
    },
    "allowedNonPeerDependencies": [
        "@type/html2canvas"
    ]
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this and do `npx ng build login-lib --watch`, it works. however, when another application in the `projects` folder use `login-lib`, it throws error `Error: dist/login-lib/app/feature/login/login.module.d.ts:5:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ng-select/ng-select' or its corresponding type declarations.

5 import * as i4 from "@ng-select/ng-select";`. do you know how to fix? i don't want `package.json` of the root folder to depend on `@ng-select-ng-select`